# Speeding up and scaling video with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using the command below to create gif thumbnails from my videos. However the "speeding up" part doesn't work - so I'm wondering if there is something I don't know? Like combining certain flags doesn't work?

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter:v "setpts=PTS/20" -t 60 -vf scale=160:-1 output.gif
```

Comment: Next time asking about ffmpeg please include the full, uncut command line output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're specifying two filters – `vf` is the same as `filter:v`:

The latter will overwrite the former, so you end up just scaling the video. Use this instead:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter:v "setpts=PTS/20,scale=160:-1" -t 60 output.gif
```

Here you specify the filter chain entries separated by a `,`.

Comment: This gives me an error: [NULL @ 0x7fd694035200] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'scale=160:-1”'
scale=160:-1”: Invalid argument

Comment: You should just replace the filter expression with the one I gave you. The output filename still needs to be there. I included the full command you need to use – maybe should have been more specific.

Comment: I used this command-line: ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter:v “setpts=PTS/20, scale=160:-1” -t 60 output.gif -- still getting the error

Comment: Ok, apparently the space after the , made it go wrong - so this is the correct filter syntax: “setpts=PTS/20,scale=160:-1”

Comment: Ah, that seems OS-dependent then. Corrected!

Comment: Never seen that issue before.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard The space thing? Me neither. It worked fine on Linux and Cygwin for me. Could have been Windows-specific.

Comment: The space issue was on OSX.

Comment: @Taapo Weird, I couldn't reproduce this on OS X with both Bash and Zsh. If you're double-quoting the filter expression, then the space will not be interpreted as an argument separator.